# Query data from multi keys sorted sets in redis

Tags: database, algorithm, redis

I have several sorted sets stored in redis. Like:

**ZADD tag:1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6  6**

**ZADD tag:2 21 1 22 2 23 3 24 4 25 5 26 6**

**ZADD tag:3 31 1 32 2 33 3 34 4 35 5 36 6**

Here is my question: I want to get the data sorted by scores in tag:1 and tag:2, or tag:1 and tag:3, or tag:1,tag:2,and tag:3. That means I need to get data from different key combination(**[** 1 **]**  **[** 2 **]** **[** 3 **]** **[** 1,2,3 **]** **[** 1,2 **]** **[** 2, 3 **]** **[** ... **]** ). I have hundreds of this kind of sorted sets, with each sorted set that can be combined to any one/two/more of the others.

I kinda not choosing the **ZUNIONSTORE**, cause all the combination is temporary, and **ZUNIONSTORE** will create another new sorted set, and this set will have very low possibility for reusing. So is there any good idea to solve my problem, or any new solution to help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't want CPU / memory usage on redis for ZUNIONSTORE / LUA, you can just send all the ZSETS to a client and do the computation from outside redis (reimplementing ZUNIONSTORE in another runtime), but you will spam network by doing so (all values on TCP). Choose which part will carry the cost (network or CPU/memory). You can also run small ZUNIONSTORE on a few ZSETS in a periodic fashion, until you use all of them and get the big result.

Comment: Thanks, @zenbeni. Just as you said, netwokr/cpu/memory, I should choose one.

Answer (score 2):

Despite your reluctance, use ZUNIONSTORE for this. Once you're done, just DEL the result. This workflow can be embedded in a Lua script that performs the actions and returns the unified result.

Comment: Thanks @Itamar Haber. Maybe my solution is not a good one. So ZUNIONSTORE a new big one and then delete, for performance this costs too much. Thanks anyway. I try to get the range indexes of each sorted set in advance, this maybe a little better.